# User-defined Color Palette for Linux(or PuTTY?)

Tags: linux, putty

As my title states, I'm only SSHing into my Linux Box. I decided to try to use the OSC escape code, but I'm pretty sure you can guess what happened.

Okay, back to my question. Can I set my own color-palette( on Linux? Even just 16 colors is fine, I just want to get it working.

Anyways, here's the code that I have tried, despite it being useless:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("\x1b]P10000ff");
        printf("\x1b[38;5;1mTest\n\x1b[0m");
        printf("\x1b]P1bb0000");
        return 0;
}
```

Edit: It worked after I retested it: here's a little "change:"

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("\x1b]P400ff00");
        printf("\x1b[38;5;4mTest\n\x1b[0m");
        printf("\x1b]P2bb0000");
        return 0;
}
```

Edit2: I'm sorry for being stupid and didn't realize that the reset works "globally" and thus, all past prints are also affected when you change back the color palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was encountering is that the colors will also set the colors of the previous letters, and hence the change only occurred in a very short time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the colors based on the C code you are writing or would you prefer to change the shell settings in your user profile?

If you just want to change your shell color: [bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/)

Or this:
[Bash - tip_colors](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

But if you are still intent on C programming:
[C Programming - Linux – Color text output](http://ramprasadk.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/c-programming-linux-color-text-output/)

Code away!